# why is abort method called?

Tags: c++, exception

In the following program `abort` method is called even when I have got the applicable catch statement. What is the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    try {
        cout << "inside try\n";
        throw "Text";
    }
    catch (string x) {
        cout << "in catch" << x << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done with try-catch\n";
}
```

When I run the program I only get the first statement `inside try` displayed and then I get this error:

[image]

Why does `abort` get called even when I am handling `string` exception?

Comment: I have fixed your formatting and use of the non-existent word "i".

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal what do you mean by `abort` is not a "method" ?

Comment: @steve: (a) "method" is general OO terminology that nonetheless has no strict meaning in C++. It could mean any number of things, and is ambiguous. I discourage the use of the term _entirely_ in C++. (b) Even in the wider OO meaning, it means "member function". `abort()` is not a member function. `abort()` _is a [free] function; nothing more, nothing less._

Comment: All C++ books with examples of throwing char * literals should be burned. Burning their authors deserves consideration.

Comment: **All C++ books with examples of throwing char * literals should be burned.** why so? is it bad programming practice or something else?

Comment: @Azodious: See phresnel's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quite simple really!

You threw `char const*`, but do not have a matching `catch` for it.

Did you mean `throw std::string("...");`?

Comment: And while you are at it, catch by reference.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal but when i am using double quotes during throw ,  am i not sending a string ?

Comment: @Suhail: No. `"..."` is a "string literal", an array of `char`s. `std::string` objects don't magically manifest: you have to create them. You may have been confused by the fact that `std::string` can be constructed from `char const*`, so the conversion happens automagically during a function call. But when you write `void f(const std::string&); f("lol");`, `"lol"` is _not_ an `std::string`.. it is merely being turned into one because of implicit conversion magic. That doesn't happen for exceptions.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal why don't you call `abort()` a method ?

Comment: @Suhail: See my response to steve under the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to be catching a char const*, not an std::string!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what the other answers tell, as a general advice: Only throw what is derived from `std::exception`, and if nothing else, in your top-handler, catch `std::exception&` or `const std::exception&`. This would have e.g. avoided this situation. See also

- [C++ FAQ 17.2: What should I throw](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.12)
- [C++ FAQ 17.3: What should I catch](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.13)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I wasn't fully sure: If he did throw e.g. a runtime_error, and caught e.g. std::exception, it would have solved his issue.

Comment: He was throwing `char const*` and catching `std::string`. It's right there up in the code.

Comment: I've refined my answer a bit. Personally, I don't see a problem with proposing alternative ways if they are better and would have prevented the reason for the question.

Comment: I agree. This is an answer and should be an answer. SO people are always so rigid, even against good sense.

Answer (score 0):

change type to `char*` and it works as expected.

Comment: [No, it doesn't](http://codepad.org/ddLnaJav). You meant `char const*`, [like this](http://codepad.org/ZY57LXSW).

Comment: On my machine, without const modifier also it's working. and catch block executes. what could be the reason?

Comment: Your machine is from an alternate reality.

Comment: Are you saying that, when you run the code I linked to under "No, it doesn't", the program builds and runs and gives the same output as the code I linked to under "like this"?

Comment: Yes, both code blocks are showing same output. 
`inside try
in catchText
Done with try-catch
Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: This is not possible. Either your computer is from a parallel universe or you have some odd compiler switches going on.